# How to lock a document while updating Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am using elasticsearch-dsl python library with my python code. I was trying to update the document, so to avoid the concurrency race conditions i  need to acquire and free lock on a document. How to do this using this library. I have already gone through it's [documentation](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html) but didn't find anything to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to avoid concurrency issues with elasticsearch is not locking but instead using the `version` metadata ([0]). To do that simply make sure that the document contains the proper version in its `.meta` dictionary. this is done by default if the document has been retrieved using the `get` API or when specifying `.extra(version=True)` on the `Search` object ([1]).

0 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_parameters_2
1 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-version.html